# Invoking another script as a different user from within a perl script

Tags: perl

We have a perl script that runs as a user x.  This script needs to invoke/run another script as user y (Only y has privileges to run that script)  Can someone help me with the different ways in which this can be done?

**EDIT**  The OS would be Sun Solaris 5.10

Comment: My bad.  Added it to the edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Sudo](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sudo) module.